# How can I use a child component in the parent component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have this situation:

Parent component(Parent.vue):

```js
<template>
........
</template>
    
<script>
export default {
name: 'Parent'
...........
</script
```

---

Child component (Child.vue):

```js
<template>
........
</template>
    
<script>
export default {
name: 'Child'
...........
</script
```

What needs to be done in order to use the child component (child component template) within the parent component's template? What are the steps?

Comment: You will learn how to use from [Vue guide: Component Basic](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html). Ex: in `Parent.vue`, uses `<template><child></child></template>`

Comment: does the child component need to be registered first? if so, how should it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the Child as a local component [as stated in the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html).

Declare the component as an object at `components`.

Parent.vue :

```js
<template>
    <child></child>
</template>

<script>
//Import the Child component to the parent
import Child from "@/path/to/Child.vue";

export default {
    name: 'Parent',//Declare the components object 
    components: {
        //Declare your components here
        Child //This is the Child component
    }
...........
</script>
```

Comment: Could you explain to me the code lines inserted and in which order should they be inserted? thanks

Comment: I inserted the import: ```import Child from "@/path/to/Child.vue";``` in order to call the Child component in the Parent component

Comment: And inserted ```components: {Child}``` after the Parent ```name```, because that's how the Parent knows it has to use the Child component, you can declare more components like ```components: {Child1, Child2, Child3}```

Comment: For further info, check the [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html), it has a lot of examples.

Comment: thanks, is the insertion of the <child> </child> tag in the parent component template, the last step after: 1) import Child from "@/path/to/Child.vue"; and 2) components: {Child} ?? is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that'd be the last step.

Comment: One last thing, in the example you gave me, Parent.vue is the .vue file of the parent component, while Child.vue is the .vue file of the child component.  right?

Comment: Yes, Child.vue is the .vue file of the child component.